# Capturar evento do botão power do android com a tela bloquiada

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

Preciso capturar o evento do botão de power off do android, e fazer com que quando ele seja pressionado uma certa quantidade de vezes, apareça uma activty por cima da tela de digitar senha.

1. Pressionou 5x o botão de power
2. Cria activity

Se isso não for possível, queria saber como faço para abrir a activity mas antes dela solicitar o desbloqueio.

O programador aqui da empresa conseguiu capturar o evento do botão power, mas disse que o resto não é possível.

Comment: Olá, Davi. Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow. Sugiro tentar resolver um problema de cada vez. Se for preciso, publique mais de uma pergunta, cada uma completa com código do que você tentou e descobriu até o momento.

Comment: Editei a pergunta Pablo, obrigado.

Comment: veja isto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703071/how-to-hook-into-the-power-button-in-android